# Fatal error: Call to undefined function msg_get_queue()

Tags: php, apache

I am trying to run a script on my local machine, I am on MAC OSX leopard. I have PHP 5.2.x installed and Apache2. I am trying to test this script but I keep getting this error. I googled around a little and saw something where it said it might only be available on linux/unix machines but I find that hard to believe.

Comment: Do you have your php compiled with `--enable-sysvmsg` option?

Comment: What @dev says: http://www.php.net/manual/en/sem.installation.php

Comment: I don't think I did, but I will take a look into that link Pekka

Answer (score 0):

Try enabling the `--enable-sysvmsg`. The config.m4 file only checks for the header sys/msg.h, so it should work in Mac OSX.

Answer (score 0):

Is support for those methods built into your PHP install? It looks as though you need to explicitly compile PHP with Semaphore, Shared Memory and IPC support.

[Semaphore, Shared Memory and IPC: Installation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/sem.installation.php)

Comment: Thanks Brian, Looking into it now