# Call to undefined function msg_get_queue() in Windows 7

Tags: php, xampp

I am using Windows 7, xampp version 1.8.1 and php version 5.4.7

Here is the problematic code

```
 $queue = msg_get_queue(100379);
```

I am getting this error:

> Call to undefined function msg_get_queue()

Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2850352/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-msg-get-queue or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7330732/php-fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-msg-get-queue-in

Answer (score 0):

You need to install Semaphore extension before accessing the functions

Reference 
http://www.php.net/manual/en/sem.installation.php

Installation

Support for this functions are not enabled by default. To enable System V semaphore support compile PHP with the option --enable-sysvsem . To enable the System V shared memory support compile PHP with the option --enable-sysvshm . To enable the System V messages support compile PHP with the option --enable-sysvmsg .

Comment: can you give me some tutorial link it will be help full. thanks.